# Lambda: cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection'", although mongoose layer added

Tags: mongoose, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, nestjs, aws-lambda-layers

I have a NestJS app, in my handler file I import mongoose to create the connection:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
let conn = null;
const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  // log something
});
```

then, in my handler function:

```
export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  if (conn == null) {
    conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, {
      bufferCommands: false, // Disable mongoose buffering
      bufferMaxEntries: 0, // and MongoDB driver buffering
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
  }
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

Now I have deployed & tested my app fully without mongoose and everything works.

Relevant serverless config:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-plugin-optimize
  - serverless-offline
package:
  individually: true
```

And I have added a mongoose layer, inside the zip I had a folder called 'nodejs' inside of which I have package.json and "node_modules" folders containing all dependencies as installed by npm.

I have used layers before that have worked without issues installed in the same manner.

However, I am still getting this on the console when trying any endpoint:

```
 "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:36:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)",
        "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)",
        "    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: @TimRooke `^5.6.9` but I think I found the issue -- it seems to be caused by `serverless-plugin-optimize` and the way it converts the whole project, not by mongoose itself. Things work ok if I'm using `serverless-plugin-monorepo` to bundle my app but then my function is 40+mb vs the 2mb with optimize.

Comment: Seems so... https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-optimize/issues/56
That thread seems to suggest `5.2.5` if that's an option?

Comment: @TimRooke tried, doesn't work, I've now excluded mongoose completely and added it as a layer with all of its dependencies. But now I'm getting other errors that are optimize-related/irelevant to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to the work of 'serverless-plugin-optimize' which I have had to remove in the end and simply use a lambda layer for my dependencies.